# auth http server 127.0.0.1:9000 did not send server or port while in http auth state- mail proxy nginx

Tags: nginx

I am absolute newbie to nginx, What i am trying to do is :

1. Setup and configure nginx (from source v1.16.1) on AWS (nginx as mail proxy)- *server status ok..
2. Using stunnel(v5.56)to upstream to G-Suit API, during login authentication from mail client (eg:Thunderbird), the server disconnects and give an error message.

> **/nginx/error.log:** " auth http server 127.0.0.1:9000 did not send server or port while in http auth state, client: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, server:
>   0.0.0.0:993, login: "user1@domain.jp"

Here is **/nginx.conf**

```
user nginx;
worker_processes 1;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;
load_module /usr/lib/nginx/modules/ngx_mail_module.so;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  info;
events {
    worker_connections 1024;
    multi_accept on;
}

mail {
server_name  example.com;
auth_http localhost:9000/api/mail/proxyauth;

    #ssl                 on;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;
    ssl_certificate     /etc/ssl/certs/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/certs/server.key;
    ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers         HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    ssl_session_cache   shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_session_timeout 10m;

  server {
    listen     995 ssl;
    protocol   pop3;
    proxy      on;
    proxy_pass_error_message on;
  }
   server {
    listen    993 ssl;
    protocol   imap;
    proxy      on;
    proxy_pass_error_message on;
    imap_auth login plain;
  }
    server {
    listen     465 ssl;
    protocol   smtp;
    proxy      on;
    proxy_pass_error_message on;
    xclient    off;
    smtp_auth  login;
 }
}
```

And **/stunnel.conf**

```
[https]
accept  = 9000
connect = gsuit1domain.com:443
delay = yes
```

What must be possible cause of the error?

Answer (score 0):

The `auth_http` directive is a HTTP server whose only role is to validate the login credentials. It's not where the connection is made (it's not the endpoint of the mail service).

If I understand correctly, you don't need Stunnel, replace `server_name example.com` by `server_name gsuit1domain.com`, and set up a HTTP server on port 9000 that's implementing [this protocol](http://nginx.org/en/docs/mail/ngx_mail_auth_http_module.html)